# ReactDOMServer not rendering components to string (third-party libraries - react-mathjax)

Tags: reactjs, dom, mathjax, react-dom, render-to-string

I'm using the package [react-mathjax](https://github.com/SamyPesse/react-mathjax) to include some math notations in a React component.

Due to a project specificity (which I won't go into here to simplify the question),
I need to convert this component to a string and inject the html string into a div using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

This is the component:

```js
import MathJax from "react-mathjax";

const Math = () => (
  <MathJax.Provider>
    <MathJax.Node inline formula="x=2" />
  </MathJax.Provider>
);
```

For some reason when I try to convert it to a string using `ReactDOMServer` it doesn't work (it returns a empty string):

```js
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Math />); // first attempt

const htmlStaticMarkup = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<Math />); // second attempt
```

If I render the `Math` component directly it works. And if I wrap the `Math` component with some default HTML tags and convert it to string, the default HTML tags are converted (but the `Math` component is ignored).
So, there is no problem with the `Math` component neither with the `ReactDOMServer` to convert default HTML tags.

Any idea?

This is a demo using CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-payne-uvww0?file=/src/App.js

This is the full source code:

```js
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import MathJax from "react-mathjax";

const Math = () => (
  <MathJax.Provider>
    <MathJax.Node inline formula="x=2" />
  </MathJax.Provider>
);

const CustomHtml = () => (
  <span>
    <Math />
    <p>Common HTML</p>
  </span>
);

const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<CustomHtml />);
const htmlStaticMarkup = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<CustomHtml />);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <p>Using the Math component and some default HTML directly: </p>
      <CustomHtml />

      <p>Using the Math component and some default HTML tags as a string (ReactDOMServer.renderToString): </p>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />

      <p>Using the Math component and some default HTML tags as a string (ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup): </p>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlStaticMarkup }} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you doing SSR? If so, MathJax implementations typically only run in the browser so if you wanna do serverside rendering, you should download the original mathjax npm package and render the math in the backend and then stringify it. I don't even think that the math component in your example is rendered in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Add a function like this

```
const returnMathMl = (data) => {

    return (
      <span
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `${data}`.replace(/\n[\s]*/g, ''),
        }}
      />
    );
  };
```

and wrap your component with MathJax, your code should look something like this

```
const returnMathMl = (data) => {

    return (
      <span
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `${data}`.replace(/\n[\s]*/g, ''),
        }}
      />
    );
  };


return (
      <MathJax>
       {returnMathMl(myData)}
      </MathJax>
    );
```

Comment: I'm using better-react-mathjax https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax